# Determine at compile time if VC++ is express version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express, visual-studio-macros

I develop an open source library. It has optional functionality for MFC. Now the MFC stuff is compiled out for other compilers by checking if the macro _MSC_VER is defined. But users of VC++ Express complain that this gives compile errors because that doesn't have MFC. Is there a way to determine this at compile time?

I tried _MFC_VER, but that is defined in afxver_.h, and that header file is not in the express versions.

I'd prefer a solution that works for every VC++ version from 2005 to 2012, but a solution for just 2010 and 2012 would be ok.